# Custom jquery selectbox with span as value change on other select

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have different selectboxes based uppon the following code:

```
$("select").each(function(){
    var select = $(this).css('opacity', 000);
    var select = $(this).css('width', 200);
    select.wrap('<span class="select"/>');
    select.before('<span class="value"><span></span></span>');
    var selectVal = select.siblings(".value").find("span");

    function selectUpdate() {
        var newVal = select.find(':selected').text();
        selectVal.html(newVal);
    }

    select.bind('change keypress keydown keyup', selectUpdate);
    selectUpdate();
});
```

I have two selectboxes, when the value on selectbox 1 == something then selectbox 2 must change it's value to somethingelse

```
<select name="tbz" id="tbz">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="something">2</option>
</select>

<select name="prc" id="prc">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="somethingelse">2</option>
</select>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/change/ . Use $('#tbz').change to check WHEN tbz is being changed and act to $('#prc') HTML in whatever way you need :) Examples are provided on the official jQuery  api.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of stuff for your qus on net.Just search for details.I have given u the basic idea   .

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/LBx9H/1/)

```
 $("#tbz").change(function(){
        if( $(this).val()=="something"){
             $("#prc").val("somethingelse");   
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. If it was that easy :) that doesn't work see: http://jsfiddle.net/U2Bus/

Comment: when u select something in first see the second changes its value to somethingelse

Comment: Sorry updated the jsfiddle, now you will see it doesn't work.

Comment: Anybody which can help me??